# Cron Job to execute R script that updates table not working! (no error shown in console)

Tags: r, database, cron, dbi

When I run this in R, the console gives no error and it looks like the job has been setup but apparently not. The job is to update a table in database every minute and by chosing a random sample (since this is a dummy). I'm not sure what is not working.

```
library(cronR)
path = "~/Documents/GitHub/abcdef/some_folder/DBI dummy.R"
cmd = cron_rscript(path)
cron_add(cmd, frequency = "minutely", at ="3:15PM", days_of_week = c(1:5), 
         id = "Automated_scheduler_test_3", description = "Testing_for_sample")
```

This is the script i'm trying to run:

```
library(DBI)
library(dplyr)
con <- connect_to_*database*()
dbRemoveTable(connect_to_*database*(schema = "*schema name*"), "*table_name*")

sample <- sample_n((dbReadTable(connect_to_*database*(schema = "*schema name*"), "*table_name*")),5)

table_id <- Id(database="*database_name*", schema="*schema_name*", table="*table_name*")
dbWriteTable(connect_to_database(schema = "*schema name*"), table_id, sample_n(sample,5), overwrite = TRUE)
```

I'm also unable to find a log for this cron job which could confirm if the job is executing.

Comment: Does the DBI script work outside of the cron environment? Also, can you de-obfuscate the code a little? I'm not sure if you have a function named `connect_to_*database*` or if that's just a pretty way of `dbConnect`ing without showing credentials.

Comment: That's using the dbConnect without the credentials! and Yes, the DBI script does work outside the cron environment

Comment: I don't know if this has anything to do with [tag:dbi], [tag:database], or [tag:rstudio]. I suggest you change your DBI script in two ways: add logging so that you know the script was actually called correctly; and add error-detection (e.g., `try` or `tryCatch`) to determine if there is a problem with your `connect_to_database` function getting the necessary credentials when non-interactive.

Comment: For instance, is `connect_to_database` using environment variables, the `config` package, the `keyring` package, or some other way of determining authentication credentials?

Comment: Paths with spaces in the file names can also do really weird things, so I would try to avoid that if possible

Comment: Good point, @Phil. The `cronR` package apparently [uses the base `system(.)`](https://github.com/bnosac/cronR/search?q=system) function, which notoriously is horrible when dealing with arguments-with-spaces. I haven't audited `cronR`'s code, so I don't know if the `file` references are all protected from this, but the use of `system` is certainly a risk. (I'd suggest they switch to the `ps` package, it has no further dependencies.)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure

- to cron_rscript, you provide the full path as in "/home/userabc/Documents/GitHub/abcdef/some_folder/DBIdummy.R" not a relative path like when using `~` and make sure the path does not use spaces
- the cron daemon is running
- consider adding options(echo = TRUE) at the start of your R scripts in order to debug your scripts in case of errors.
- look to the log of the cron job, the path where it is you can find out when printing cmd